# What happened to the Coral TARDIS template?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

In the beginning of Matt Smith's tenure of being the Doctor you see David Tennant's ["Coral" templated TARDIS control room](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/TARDIS_coral) getting, basically, blown up and destroyed.

Therefore the Doctor has to wait a while for the TARDIS to rebuild itself.

Later in the episode called "The Doctor's Wife" we see that  the TARDIS keeps a copy of all control room templates in a room of the TARDIS.

So, ***if*** that is true, why didn't the TARDIS just 
take a copy of the old template and place it in the main control room?

<sub><sup>Yes I know it is an opportunity to use a new TARDIS set, but that is **not** what I am asking here.</sup></sub>

Comment: @Xantec -- that is not really a spoiler, and if it is, you did not block the end of the OP as well.

Comment: My bad. If you feel the edits are not necessary then please feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @Xantec I don't think **any** of it is spoilery...  rolling back.

Comment: I think the episode you are thinking of is "The Doctor's Wife", there is no episode called "House" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_serials

Comment: @NathanKinsinger haha thanks. The creature was called "House". My mistake.

Comment: Maybe that template was in cooldown, but respawns with new templates have no cooldown ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, she could have... but the Tardis, being a living being AND female, occasionally likes to change things up, or re-decorate.  It would probably require the same (or comparable) energy to copy an old template as it would to simply build a new one, so she chose to create a new one.  I'm not sure WHAT exactly determined the change, but I would guess, in her mind, the new format fit the Doctor's new 'format'.

One aspect of extremely long life is boredom; I wouldn't be surprised if the tendency to rebuild when the opportunity arises is hard coded into the Tardis matrix.

Besides... as we see in [The Doctor's Wife](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Wife), she knows (and has copies) of many control rooms.. including ones he hasn't used yet.. She simply 'grew' another variant she had a stored copy of.

Comment: The TARDIS isn't female; the TARDIS' avatar was female. The TARDIS in its proper form is utterly genderless.

Comment: *shrug*  As is the case for (arguably) most machines, gender really doesn't apply.. HOWEVER, they tend to be assigned genders (by those that interact with them) based upon visible behaviors, even if it is anthropomorphism.  Then, when you start to get into machines with some degree of consciousness and volition, you often see them adopt behaviors consistent with the way they are treated -- they have no ACTUAL gender, but they often develop one based on treatment and experience, and, over time, this can becomes rather ingrained.  YMMV; this is fiction only, so far.

Comment: I don't see what gender has to do with re-decorating.

Comment: @OrangeDog -- It's a stereotype; and, right or wrong, a well known one.

Comment: @Blazemonger  The Doctor regularly refers to the TARDIS as "she".

Answer (score -1):

It got destroyed. The TARDIS and the Doctor probably decided it was time for a change